# ionic pubnub realtime geolocation tracking not working

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, pubnub

```js
var exampleApp= angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})
exampleApp.controller('MapController', function($scope, $ionicLoading) {
 var map;
    var map_marker;
    var lat = null;
    var lng = null;
    var lineCoordinatesArray = [];

    // sets your location as default
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) { 
        var locationMarker = null;
        if (locationMarker){
          // return if there is a locationMarker bug
          return;
        }

        lat = position.coords["latitude"];
        lng = position.coords["longitude"];

        // calls PubNub
        pubs();

        // initialize google maps
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize());
      },
      function(error) {
        console.log("Error: ", error);
      },
      {
        enableHighAccuracy: true
      }
      );
    }    


    function initialize() {
      console.log("Google Maps Initialized")
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 15,
        center: {lat: lat, lng : lng, alt: 0}
      });

      map_marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: {lat: lat, lng: lng}, map: map});
      map_marker.setMap(map);
    }

    // moves the marker and center of map
    function redraw() {
      map.setCenter({lat: lat, lng : lng, alt: 0})
      map_marker.setPosition({lat: lat, lng : lng, alt: 0});
      pushCoordToArray(lat, lng);

      var lineCoordinatesPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: lineCoordinatesArray,
        geodesic: true,
        strokeColor: '#2E10FF',
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 2
      });
      
      lineCoordinatesPath.setMap(map);
    }


    function pushCoordToArray(latIn, lngIn) {
      lineCoordinatesArray.push(new google.maps.LatLng(latIn, lngIn));
    }
    

    function pubs() {
      pubnub = PUBNUB.init({
        publish_key: 'pub-c-2df55398-9110-4b2b-bdab-97bf634be349',
        subscribe_key: 'sub-c-6b2c387c-7148-11e4-86a8-02ee2ddab7fe'
      })

      pubnub.subscribe({
        channel: "mymaps",
        message: function(message, channel) {
          console.log(message)
          lat = message['lat'];
          lng = message['lng'];
          //custom method
          redraw();
        },
        connect: function() {console.log("PubNub Connected")}
      })
    }

    });
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.pubnub.com/pubnub-3.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&language=en"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">

    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
     <ion-content ng-controller="MapController">
      <div id="map" data-tap-disabled="true"></div>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>

  </body>
</html>
```

The above code contains the app.js code where i put my api key and those geolocation javascript code The error that i encounter is when i run the app the marker wont auto update and move not like the pubnub tutorial is juz check https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2015-04-30-google-maps-geolocation-tracking-in-realtime-with-javascript/ pls help me out

Comment: Hi there.  I noticed that the **`sensor=false`** in your google maps API code.  Maybe this is related?  I will help review further.

Answer (score 1):

## Ionic Geo Location Testing

You are getting a security error.  User's location and position are protected by browsers.  You need to run your project from an HTTP Server.  I recommend an HTTPS Server which you can run with one command:

```
## HTTP(S) Secure Server
python <(curl -L https://goo.gl/Rrko89)
```

> Your static files will be available on https://0.0.0.0:4443/index.html.

Alternatively you can run an insecure HTTP Server by running this command instead:

```
## HTTP Insecure Server
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

> Your **insecure** static files will be available on http://0.0.0.0:8000/index.html.

Now it will work when you see my screenshot below.

[image: Ionic Geo Location Tracking]

To run the code in Cordova PhoneGap you need enable the permissions https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.3.0/cordova/geolocation/geolocation.html

### Ionic Cordova PhoneGap Geo Permissions

#### Android

> app/res/xml/config.xml

```
<plugin name="Geolocation" value="org.apache.cordova.GeoBroker" />
```

> app/AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
```

#### iOS

> config.xml

```
<plugin name="Geolocation" value="CDVLocation" />
```

Comment: hi i want to run in app not on a browser can you help me out the example you are showing me is running on a browser not app

Comment: You will need to make sure the cordova GPS/location is enabled with Cordova. https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.3.0/cordova/geolocation/geolocation.html

Comment: nvm i will try it later again after some permission that you want me to add